# From Java to Kotlin: synchronization and lock / wait / notify pattern

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines

### Original Context

Back when developing Android / Java apps, I created a simple class that would allow to me to synchronize taks instead of using the queue logic and / or the callbacks pattern.

Indeed that would allow me to have a series of tasks being performed in a linear way (when looking at the code). In some cases, that's more useful and way more maintainable and debuggable.

The reason behind this need, is that when I am required to work with APIs that provided asynchronous logic with callbacks to be notified of result or failure, such as the Android Bluetooth LE API or Glide (to name a few), I want to be able to synchronize **my code** when using asynchronous APIs.

This is what I came up with:

### Lock.java

```
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;


/**
 * This class is a small helper to provide feedback on lock wait and notify process
 */
public final class Lock<T> {
    private final static String TAG = Lock.class.getSimpleName();

    private T result = null;
    private boolean isWaiting = false;
    private boolean wasNotified = false;


    /**
     * Releases the lock on this instance to notify the thread that was waiting and to provide the result
     * @param result    the result of the asynchronous operation that was waited
     */
    public synchronized final void setResultAndNotify(@Nullable final T result) {
        this.result = result;
        if (this.isWaiting) {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.notify();
            }
        } else
            this.wasNotified = true;
    }


    /**
     * This method locks on the current instance and wait for the duration specified in milliseconds
     * @param timeout the duration, in milliseconds, the thread will wait if it does not get notify
     */
    @Nullable
    public synchronized final T waitAndGetResult(final long timeout) {
        if (this.wasNotified) { // it might happen that the notify was performed even before the wait started!
            this.wasNotified = false;
            return this.result;
        }

        try {
            synchronized (this) {
                this.isWaiting = true;
                if (timeout < 0) {
                    this.wait();
                } else {
                    this.wait(timeout);
                }
                this.isWaiting = false;
                return this.result;
            }
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to wait, Thread got interrupted -> " + e.getMessage());
            Log.getStackTraceString(e);
        }
        return null;
    }


    /**
     * This method locks on the current instance and wait as long necessary (no timeout)
     */
    @Nullable
    public synchronized final T waitAndGetResult() {
        return waitAndGetResult(-1)
    }


    /**
     * Tells whether this instance is currently waiting or not
     * @return <code>true</code> if waiting, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public final boolean isWaiting() {
        return this.isWaiting;
    }
}
```

Not the best solution, I'm sure, but, in a way, it does take care of some race conditions in my rare cases where `notify` could be called before `wait` is. I believe I could use an `AtomicBoolean` but so far no problem.

Here is how it can be used:

```
public final boolean performLongRunningTasks() {
    this.asynchronousTaskA.startAsync();
    final Result taskAResult = this.taskALock.waitAndGetResult(); // wait forever

    this.asynchronousTaskB.startAsync();
    final Result taskBResult = this.taskBLock.waitAndGetResult(5000L); // wait up to 5 seconds

    return taskAResult != null && taskBResult != null;
}


// callback
private void onTaskACompleted(@Nullable Result result) {
    this.taskALock.setResultAndNotify(result);
}


// callback
private void onTaskBCompleted(@Nullable Result result) {
    this.taskBLock.setResultAndNotify(result);
}
```

Useful, right ? Granted, the wait for ever is no ideal.

### Migrating to Kotlin

Now I am developing in Kotlin and I have started to read about concurrency and coroutines.
There was one article, at some point, converting Java's synchronisation / lock / wait / notify pattern into Kotlin which helped me translated my original class to that:

### Lock.kt

```
import android.util.Log

class Lock<T> {

    private var result : T? = null

    private var isWaiting = false
    private var wasNotified = false

    private val lock = Object() // Java object, Urgh...

    fun setResultAndNotify(value: T?) {
        result = value
        if (isWaiting) {
            synchronized(lock) {
                lock.notify()
            }
        } else {
            wasNotified = true
        }
    }


    fun waitAndGetResult(timeout: Long) : T? {
        if (wasNotified) {
            wasNotified = false
            return result
        }

        try {
            synchronized(lock) {
                isWaiting = true
                if (timeout < 0) lock.wait() else lock.wait(timeout)
                isWaiting = false
            }
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            Log.getStackTraceString(e)
        }

        return this.result
    }


    fun waitAndGetResult() = waitAndGetResult(-1)
}
```

And no problem here it does work... But, it's Kotlin! Surely I could do better ?
What would be your solution ?

Comment: have you looked at https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-synchronized/index.html and https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/synchronized.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin in Android is compiling to same Java equivalent so you can use your legacy code in java with kotlin without problems. Then you don't have to rewrite all of the classes to kotlin. Use them "as is".

Another questions is what's the better approach? Regarding that I would say it's kotlin coroutines! They would work as your code but without any locks and other boilerplate code. The usage is very simple.

1) Add dependency:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

2) Create your suspend functions by adding `suspend` modifier to the function:

```
suspend fun someBigTask(param: Param): Result {
   //...
}
```

3) Create your scope and helper methods. Think of this as a thread where your result will be populated. I also like to create another scope for background tasks:

```
val ioScope by lazy { CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO) } // background scope

// For background processing
@Suppress("SuspendFunctionOnCoroutineScope")
private suspend inline fun <T> CoroutineScope.await(crossinline block: suspend Job.() -> T): T {
    val deferred = CompletableDeferred<T>()
    launch {
        try {
            val result = deferred.block()
            deferred.complete(result)
        } catch (throwable: Throwable) {
            deferred.completeExceptionally(throwable)
        }
    }

    return deferred.await()
}

suspend inline fun <T> doAsync(crossinline block: suspend () -> T): T {
    return ioScope.await { block() }
}
```

4) Now you're ready to launch your long running tasks:

```
val job = SupervisorJob() // the job containing your performing tasks. You can use it for canceling your tasks when it is needed.
val mainScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main) // scope of the main thread

fun launchMyJob(block: suspend () -> Unit) {
   mainScope.launch(job) {
       try {
           block()
       } catch(e: JobCancellationException) {
           // is thrown when you call job.cancel() method.
           // ignore it
       }
   }
}

fun performLongRunningTasks(param1: Param1, param2: Param2) {
   launchMyJob {
       val result1 = doAsync { someBigTask(param1) /* This operation is running in background thread */ }
       // result1 will be written only when someBigTask() is finished and coroutine will continue
       val result2 = doAsync { someBigTask(result1, param2) }

       // Here you can access views because you have result on the main thread.
       textView.text = result2.toString() 
   }
}
```

5) Cancel your job:

```
job.cancel()
```

Be careful using this method, because after you call it, the job cannot be used again and your coroutine will throw `JobCancellationException` which you should handle.

Even though it seems like synchronous code in reality everything will be performed on different threads. This is the beauty of Kotlin coroutines.

Comment: Well, thanks, I think I am getting it. Just a first question is `[...]suspend inline fun <T> CoroutineScope.await[...]` an extension that is added to `CoroutineScope` ?

Comment: yeah its a helper method that is used in `doAsync` method.

Comment: Another thing to mention is word `added` is not applicable for extensions. The extension method are not added to the object, but new method on this object is created. For instance ```fun MyObject.extFun(param: Param)``` is compiled in java to ```public static void extFun(MyObject $receiver, Param param)```
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html

Comment: Yes sorry and thank you for pointing it out :) I will test your solution and validate it if it satisfies my need !

Comment: Your solution worked. Well, in fact you put me on the right track. The solution was to use `CompletableDeferred` which acts exactly like my `Lock` but way better and with scopes, of course. So thank you very much.